# how would I go about predicting or estimating future performance based on past google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, time-series, google-analytics-api, prediction

I've hooked up to the Google Analytics API and I've logged performance numbers for the past two years into a local database. Now I would like to use this past data to predict future performance. I would like to write some code that does all that, but preferably I would like to use an existing library on Github. I've searched for terms such as "Prediction Analysis", "Time Series Prediction" and others but I couldn't find anything good, I found some really advanced machine learning projects but that's way too advanced. Surely I can't be the first person to want this, I'm probably just using the wrong terms to locate it

Answer (score 0):

Python is probably your best bet for doing data analytics and machine learning. The pandas package is good for data exploration. Scikit-learn (sklearn) makes it really easy to implement models and there is Tensorflow/keras for neural networks.

This article is the first in a helpful series on predicting with time series data. https://www.ethanrosenthal.com/2018/01/28/time-series-for-scikit-learn-people-part1/

The author uses his skits (SciKit-learn-Inspired Time Series) library for predicting with time series data. The articles are verbose for a ML beginner, but the code snippets are helpful for getting started.

There is also tsfresh (https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is good for extracting features from time series data.